ERROR: Failed building wheel for av Running setup.py clean for av Failed to build av
when I try to install a library in conda environment of windows by using: pip install tobiiglassesctrl
then I get the error as following:
(sensor_env_py37) C:\Users>pip install tobiiglassesctrl
Collecting tobiiglassesctrl
  Using cached tobiiglassesctrl-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: netifaces in c:\users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages (from tobiiglassesctrl) (0.11.0)
Collecting opencv-python==4.2.0.32 (from tobiiglassesctrl)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.2.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting av==8.0.3 (from tobiiglassesctrl)
  Using cached av-8.0.3.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python==4.2.0.32->tobiiglassesctrl) (1.21.6)
Using cached tobiiglassesctrl-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Using cached opencv_python-4.2.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (33.0 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: av
  Building wheel for av (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-av8l__4b\av_c2edd971473c41f7a92c409e6e451f13\setup.py", line 541, in <module>
          distclass=distclass,
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 172, in setup
          ok = dist.parse_command_line()
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
          args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1132, in _parse_command_opts
          nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 534, in _parse_command_opts
          cmd_class = self.get_command_class(command)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 979, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 208, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 3, in <module>
          from ._bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel as bdist_wheel
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\wheel\_bdist_wheel.py", line 21, in <module>
          from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, Iterable, Literal, Sequence, cast
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\typing.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for av
  Running setup.py clean for av
Failed to build av
ERROR: Could not build wheels for av, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

then I try to install the av by using: pip install av
(sensor_env_py37) C:\Users>pip install av
Requirement already satisfied: av in c:\users\xzhou42.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages (10.0.0)
but when I try to install tobiiglassesctrl by using: pip install tobiiglassesctrl
I get the following content:
(sensor_env_py37) C:\Users>pip install tobiiglassesctrl
Collecting tobiiglassesctrl
  Using cached tobiiglassesctrl-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: netifaces in c:\users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages (from tobiiglassesctrl) (0.11.0)
Collecting opencv-python==4.2.0.32 (from tobiiglassesctrl)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.2.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting av==8.0.3 (from tobiiglassesctrl)
  Using cached av-8.0.3.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python==4.2.0.32->tobiiglassesctrl) (1.21.6)
Using cached tobiiglassesctrl-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Using cached opencv_python-4.2.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (33.0 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: av
  Building wheel for av (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3pvby8v9\av_2eb684df385c4188be7962f3d791c897\setup.py", line 541, in <module>
          distclass=distclass,
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 172, in setup
          ok = dist.parse_command_line()
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
          args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1132, in _parse_command_opts
          nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 534, in _parse_command_opts
          cmd_class = self.get_command_class(command)
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 979, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 208, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 3, in <module>
          from ._bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel as bdist_wheel
        File "C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\site-packages\wheel\_bdist_wheel.py", line 21, in <module>
          from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, Iterable, Literal, Sequence, cast
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (C:\Users\xzhou42\.conda\envs\sensor_env_py37\lib\typing.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for av
  Running setup.py clean for av
Failed to build av
ERROR:Could not build wheels for av, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError+%22cannot+import+name+Literal+from+typing%22
